# upload multiple files using java

Tags: java

I want to upload multiple files using java: are there any articles on the subject?

Comment: upload to .. where and what? ftp? webservice?

Comment: Please don't use lolcats to improve your English. Are you sure you want to use Java, and not ECMAScript - better known at "JavaScript"?

Comment: how long is a piece of string?

Comment: `strlen` if it's null-terminated

Comment: wat a marvelous question?????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. If you mean using Javascript then you can use libraries like extjs that provide control for multiple uploads

Comment: i thought he wanted to use java?

Comment: yes but - it appeared that the person asking the question was unclear about it and so the answer was suggestive of the options.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an excellent Java applet for uploading multiple files, including full source:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jupload/

Comment: Another Java applet you might want to try: [JCustomUploader](http://dound.com/projects/JCustomUploader) (multiple files, drag and drop, parallel uploads, only needs Java 1.4+)

Answer (score 0):

if you use java for web you can use jsp :

http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/file_upload/uploadingMultipleFiles.shtml

Comment: I'd also link directly to the Apache Commons project discussed in the tutorial - FileUpload - http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/

Comment: Though I've usually handled file uploads in a servlet rather than directly in the JSP... separation of presentation and control...

Comment: RoseIndia is the **worst** source when it comes to the practices used in code examples. I wouldn't mention it to new-to-java users.

Answer (score 0):

Apache MINA has a ftp server written in Java - http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/ - could easily be used with any ftp client to upload multiple files.

Comment: And what if the external server goes down?